# Cocos2d call scheduleOnce selector twice causes crash

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

CCsprite scheduleOnce selector when called twice causes crash.

```
Assertion failure in -[CCScheduler scheduleSelector:forTarget:interval:paused:repeat:delay:], /Users/libs/cocos2d/CCScheduler.m:278    

[sprite scheduleOnce:@selector(resumeSchedulerAndActions) delay:time];
```

Any solutions to overcome this?

Comment: you have the code of the cocos2d framework. why cannot you just see assertion message in the CCScheduler class at the line 278?

Comment: CCScheduler. Trying to schedule a selector with a pause value different than the target - This is what the assertion says but its not clear and the assertion is not in the method I have called, its actually a sub method.

Comment: From several lines of code across this assertion you can see, that there is no possibility to schedule method until previous schedule is active. If you need to do it several times, you can create and run CCSequences of CCDelayTime and CCCallFunc actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @LearnCocos2D and @Morion.
I got it solved by calling.

`[sprite unscheduleAllSelectors];`

before calling

`[sprite scheduleOnce:@selector(resumeSchedulerAndActions:) delay:time];`

Answer (score 1):

Your scheduled selector does not use the correct format. It needs to take one parameter of type ccTime. The scheduled selector needs to have a colon at the end:

```
[sprite scheduleOnce:@selector(resumeSchedulerAndActions:) delay:time];
```

And it must have this interface:

```
-(void) resumeSchedulerAndActions:(ccTime)delta
{
    // here you can "forward" to the actual method you wanted to schedule
    [self resumeSchedulerAndActions];
}
```

Comment: There is no problem in calling the scheduler once, if it is called more than once. And the issue is not with the format, its actually a method available in CCNode

Comment: It may work once, but it's an illegal call. Cocos2D *always* sends the delta time parameter to a scheduled method. If the scheduled method does not take a single ccTime parameter, bad things might happen even though this may not be an immediately visible issue. The call will send an extraneous parameter on the stack, which I believe will corrupt the stack for at least the receiving function.

Comment: Add the preprocessor macro COCOS2D_DEBUG=1 to your build settings (or build a debug configuration if you were building release) and you'll get an assertion. The message you'll get from line 193 in CCScheduler.m is: "Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use CCDirector scheduler.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].scheduler scheduleSelector:@selector(resumeSchedulerAndActions:) forTarget:self interval:0.1 repeat:0 delay:2 paused:NO];
```